# C# - Feedback on adress book - OOP - Console Application

Tags: c#, oop, project

I have been taking some C# online-courses the last couple of weeks in order to learn programming. Since I dont have any friends that are programming I found it hard to get feedback / reviews on the code im writing. Sure the code is running, but how about the code quaility?

To avoid the worst beginner mistakes I would really approtiate if anyone could take a quick look on the code below or direct me to some other forum where code review is a topic.
(Just remove this thread if this is an incorrect approach on SO).

**About the project**

I have created a simple Adress Book (console application) based on four classes:

- Main
- AdressBook
- Person
- WriteAndReadToFile

The application has the following abilities:

- Store friends
- Update friend information
- Remove user
- Show all users
- When adding/update/remove user it should be stored on a txt-file (which is loaded when the program start).

For simplicity I only added only name and adress in the application, there is also very bad data-input validation (focusing in learing OOP). Regarding the update function I am aware that it will update everything wich have a match on firstName.

**Questions**

- Im I addapting OOP in a correct way?
- I found it hard to keep the text-file in a correct "state" after updates & deletes and begun to flush the file after and rewrite the file instead. Is that bad practice?

**Code**

**Main**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool ProgramIsRunning = true;
        AdressBook ab = StartProgram();

        Console.WriteLine("--------- AdressBook 1.0 ---------");

        while (ProgramIsRunning)
        {
            // Print user options
            PrintUserOptions();
            var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (userInput)
            {
                case "1":
                    ab.CreateUser();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    ab.UpdateUserInformation();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    ab.RemovePersonFromList();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    ab.ShowAllPersonsInList();
                    break;
                case "x":
                    ProgramIsRunning = false;
                    break;
            }    
        }
    }

    private static void PrintUserOptions()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Choose one of the following options: ");
        Console.WriteLine("#1 Create new user");
        Console.WriteLine("#2 Edit user information");
        Console.WriteLine("#3 Delete existing user");
        Console.WriteLine("#4 Show all users in adressBook");
    }

    private static AdressBook StartProgram()
    {
        AdressBook ab = new AdressBook();

        //Start program by loading saved users from txt-file
        WriteAndReadToFile writer = new WriteAndReadToFile();
        writer.ReadFromFile(ab);
        return ab;
    }
}
```

**Person**

```
    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Adress { get; set; }

        public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string adress)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.Adress = adress;
        }
    }
}
```

**AdressBook**

```
class AdressBook
{
    private WriteAndReadToFile wtf;
    private List<Person> adressBookList = new List<Person>();
    public List<Person> AdressBookList
    {
        get { return adressBookList; }
        set { this.adressBookList = value; }
    }


    public AdressBook()
    {
        AdressBookList = new List<Person>();
        wtf = new WriteAndReadToFile();
    }

    // Create instance of Person-class and call AddPersonToList-method
    public void CreateUser()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter firstName:");
        var firstName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter lastName:");
        var lastName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter adress:");
        var adress = Console.ReadLine();

        Person person = new Person(firstName, lastName, adress);
        AddPersonToList(person);
        wtf.WriteUserToFile(person);

    }

    // Add new person to AdressBookList
    private void AddPersonToList(Person person) => AdressBookList.Add(person);

    //Remove user from list where first and last name match
    public void RemovePersonFromList()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter firstName of the user you want to remove");
        var firstName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter lastname of the user you want to remove");
        var lastName = Console.ReadLine();

        AdressBookList.RemoveAll(item => item.FirstName == firstName && item.LastName == lastName);
        wtf.UpdateUserOnFile(adressBookList);
    }

    //Show all Persons in AdressBookList
    public void ShowAllPersonsInList()
    {
        foreach (var person in AdressBookList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FirstName: {0}, LastName: {1}, Adress: {2}", person.FirstName, person.LastName, person.Adress);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateUserInformation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Which information do you want to update?");
        Console.WriteLine("#1: Firstname, #2: Lastname, 3# Adress");
        var userOption = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter firstname on existing user to be updated");
        var oldFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
        UpdateUserFunction(userOption, oldFirstName);
    }

    private void UpdateUserFunction(string userOption, string oldFirstName)
    {
        var personsWithMatchingFirstName = AdressBookList.Where(person => person.FirstName == oldFirstName);
        string newValue;

        if(userOption == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a new first Name");
            newValue = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (var person in personsWithMatchingFirstName)
            {
                person.FirstName = newValue;
                wtf.UpdateUserOnFile(adressBookList);
            }
        }
        else if (userOption == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a new last name");
            newValue = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (var person in personsWithMatchingFirstName)
            {
                person.LastName = newValue;
                wtf.UpdateUserOnFile(adressBookList);
            }
        }
        else if(userOption == "3")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a new adress");
            newValue = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (var person in personsWithMatchingFirstName)
            {
                person.Adress = newValue;
                wtf.UpdateUserOnFile(adressBookList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**WriteToFile**

```
class WriteAndReadToFile
{

    private readonly string UserTextFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["textFileName"];

    public void WriteUserToFile(Person person)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(UserTextFile, true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(person.FirstName + "," + person.LastName + "," + person.Adress + ",");
        }         
    }

    public void ReadFromFile(AdressBook ab)
    {
        string textLine;
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(UserTextFile))
            {
                while ((textLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] userInformation = textLine.Split(',');
                    Person p = new Person(userInformation[0], userInformation[1], userInformation[2]);
                    ab.AdressBookList.Add(p);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnf)
        {          
           Console.WriteLine("File does not exist " + fnf);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong" + e);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateUserOnFile(List<Person> adressBookList)
    {
       // Remove old row
       using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(UserTextFile))
        {
            sw.Flush();
            foreach (var person in adressBookList)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(person.FirstName + "," + person.LastName + "," + person.Adress + ",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For feedback on working code post to [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: That's a really well-asked question so have an upvote! I'm sure you'll get advice on the forum @JJJ suggested

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Posting it in code review instead!